How can I automatically change measurement system based on country?
I’d like Maps to change measurement systems automatically when I drive across the border. Specifically, I’d like it to use miles in the US and km in Canada. The best way would be an option in Settings to use the measurement systems based on location. But since Apple hasn’t chosen to (re-)implement that (I think it was possible in the very early days of Maps but hasn’t been possible for a very long time if ever) is there a way to do that, perhaps using location-based automation?
I’ve tried in Shortcuts, but I can’t see a way to either get it to trigger based on being in a country or to change the Measurement System (Settings > General > Language & Region > Measurement System).
